# Magento 2.2: Redirect to category page after add to cart

Tags: magento2, redirect

I am trying to redirect to the product category page, the process enters through the **getCategoryUrl** function but has never just redirected to the category. I have tried many functions and none is effective.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

```
if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
   if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
      $message = __(
      __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.'),
         $product->getName()
       );
       $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
    }
    if (key_exists('pg_category_from', $params)) {
        $categoryId = $params['pg_category_from'];
           if ($categoryId) {
               return $this->getCategoryUrl($categoryId);
         }
      }
 return $this->goBack('*/*');
}



private function getCategoryUrl($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($category->getUrl());
}
```

Comment: You are using observer for this?

Comment: @Sumit no, I replace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add controller for this.